# Tkinter redirect stdout crash with KeyError : 'None'

Tags: python, tkinter, stdout

I got this looks weird problem that sometimes my tkinter application crashed with KeyError : 'None'. It's very unstable:(

Here is my redirect class, I just followed some others from internet, I dont have much understanding about it.

This code was invoked by my serial monitor which basically prints out received data.

> File "D:\work\tools\eclipseWorkspace\myDemo\mySerialPort.py", line
>   119, in readSerial
>   print serBuffer
>   File "D:\work\tools\eclipseWorkspace\myDemo\mySerialPort.py", line 56, in
>   write
>       self.widget.winfo_toplevel().update()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 954,
>     in winfo_toplevel
>       'winfo', 'toplevel', self._w))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1200,
>
> in nametowidget w = w.children[n]
>
> KeyError: 'None'

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag
        self.file = open("message.log","w")

    def write(self, msg):
        if msg == None:
            return
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", msg, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")
        self.widget.see(END)
        self.widget.winfo_toplevel().update()
        self.file.write(msg)

    def flush(self):
        self.file.flush()
```

Comment: Not sure why that's happening, but try `self.widget.update()` instead - I don't think it matters what widget you invoke `update()` on.

Comment: Thanks Jason, will try yours, I currently resolved this by adding exception 
" except KeyError:
            pass"

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone could figure out the root cause, currently my solution is except KeyError, I also tried with Jason's advice, so my current code looks like this:

```
try:
    self.widget.update()
except KeyError:
    pass
```